# DB2 raise application trigger

Tags: database, triggers, db2, database-trigger

I've defined this trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER actualizarSaldoRetirada
BEFORE INSERT ON Retirada
REFERENCING NEW AS N
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT Saldo FROM Cuenta WHERE IBAN = N.Cuenta_IBAN) - N.Cantidad >= 0 THEN
        UPDATE Cuenta SET Saldo = Saldo - N.Cantidad WHERE IBAN = N.Cuenta_IBAN;
    ELSE
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'El saldo de la cuenta no puede ser negativo');
    END IF;
END@
```

But db2 returns the following error

```
An unexpected token "RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR" was found following ".Cuenta_IBAN; ELSE "
```

Any ideas to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the [RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.plsql.doc/doc/c0053877.html) is available only in pl/sql contexts.
Consider using [SIGNAL](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004232.html)  instead.

For example (choose your own suitable SQLSTATE value from a valid range):

```
CREATE TRIGGER actualizarSaldoRetirada
BEFORE INSERT ON Retirada
REFERENCING NEW AS N
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
BEGIN 
    IF (select saldo from cuenta where iban = N.cuenta_iban  ) - N.Cantidad >= 0 THEN
        UPDATE Cuenta SET Saldo = Saldo - N.Cantidad WHERE IBAN = N.Cuenta_IBAN;
    ELSE
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '75002' set message_text= 'El saldo de la cuenta no puede ser negativo';
    END IF;
END
```